# Authorizing Hadoop users without Sentry

Tags: hadoop, hive, permissions, impala

I have a Kerberized CDH cluster, where there are some daily oozie workflows running. All of them use `shell`, `impala-shell`, `hive` and `sqoop` to ingest data to Hive tables (lets call these tables `SensitiveTables`)

Now, I want to create 2 new BI users to use the cluster and experiment with some other ingested data.

The requirement is that these new BI users:

- should **not** have access to the `SensitiveTables`
- should be able to `spark-submit` jobs to the cluster
- (optionally) use Hue

Apart from setting-up [Apache Sentry](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sentry_intro.html#sentry_overview) (which is the recommended way to go), is there any chance to meet those requirements using file-permissions or ACL and Service Level Authorization ?

So far, I managed (via `hadoop fs -chmod o-rwx /user/hive/warehouse/sensitive`) to restrict access to `SensitiveTables` via Hive (which uses user impersonation), but failed to do so via Impala (which submits all jobs to the cluster as user `impala`). Is there anything else I should try?

Thank you,

Gee

Comment: Sure, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Sentry is not that difficult to set up. It's just an additional **SPOF** (or rather 2, since it does not support Metastore HA). On the bonus side, it will take care of the HDFS bug about ACLs that do not propagate correctly (not fixed until Hadoop 3).

Comment: Looks like Cloudera did a deliberate job of not developing proper authorization in Impala, to lock people into Sentry. But they don't seem to invest into Sentry any more; they switched to shiny new toys (Kudu, Data Science Workbench) that their Sales people can boast about. And ultimately they will switch to yet another new toy and leave all their half-baked projects behind (remember Sqoop2...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and based on the assumptions I described, the answer is NO. Furthermore, the metastore can not be protected this way.